# Where can I find the javadoc for Hibernate-JPA jar

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, javadoc

I'm using netbeans and I'm unable to find the javadoc jar/zip/folder for `hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar`.

Here is the message I get.

> > Javadoc not found. Either Javadoc documentation for this item does not exist or there is no attached Javadoc to the JAR file containing this item:C:\Users\user.m2\repository\org\hibernate\javax\persistence\hibernate-jpa-2.0-api\1.0.1.Final\hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar

I searched through [mvnrepository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api/1.0.1.Final) but I don't see a link to the javadocs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only jar and source available for `hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar`

http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/maven2/org/hibernate/javax/persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api/1.0.1.Final/

You can extract JavaDoc from RPM: http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/19977459/dir/fedora_18/com/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-javadoc-1.0.1-7.fc18.noarch.rpm.html

Extracted jar: https://www.dropbox.com/s/sqcaf9qihg27iu7/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.javadoc.jar

Comment: Was able to get the javadoc folder from the rpm. But just curious to know why there isn't an easier route for this jar

Comment: I think this is JBoss guys fault/mess, they are always using `ant` and dont understand `maven` :)

Comment: And here I am feeling lazy about myself for not yet trying out Gradle!

Comment: I think `maven` and `gradle` are good tools :) Gradle is like mavenized ant for me ;)